# Update all columns on duplicate in Insert on select

Tags: mysql

I have two tables (say t1 and t2). I want to insert all records from t2 to t1. I can do this by using the query  -

```
Insert into t1 select * from t2
```

While inserting, there might be duplicates. How to update all columns in table `t1` from the t2 table in case of duplicates. We can do it this way -

```
Insert into t1 select * from t2 on duplicate update t1.a=t2.a...
```

But there are more than 60 columns in table t2. Is there any way to update all columns at once?

Comment: can you pls provide sample data, expected output, DDL + DML commands.

Comment: for those duplicated data, should be updating instead of inserting

Comment: as I already mentioned, there are 60+ columns in the table. So it might not be possible to provide sample data

Comment: Yes for the duplicated data, I need to be updating in case of duplicating

Comment: Sample data is not all data from your actual db. Pls provide sample dat

Comment: 'there might be duplicates' - the syntax is INSERT INTO t1 .. ON DUPLICATE **KEY** UPDATE . ie it's the keys that are tested for duplicates and update portion has the same  syntax for updating multiple columns as a simple update - all columns to be updated separated by columns - if yu have 60 columns then you type in 60 columns.